# Siebel mobile application

Tags: performance, mobile, loadrunner, siebel

Can HP Load runner support to record Siebel  Mobile application for performance testing.
I want to record a siebel mobile application by using Hp Loadrunne for doing performance testing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Recording via proxy for off host is supported